# react getting observable values in component

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

Seting the obsrv array in the component below;

```
class AnnouncementState {
    @observable categories =[];
    constructor(){
        this.getAnnouncementCategory();
    }

  getAnnouncementCategory() {
    fetch(`..`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.categories = response.value.map((item , i)=>{ return {Id:item.Id, Title:item.Title} });
      }, (error) => {
      });
  }
}
```

I checked the retrieved values its ok. and I try set it in component and render it below;

```
@observer
class AnnouncementComponent extends React.Component {
  categories = [];
  componentWillMount(){
    debugger
    this.categories=this.props.announcement.categories;
  }

  render() {
    const listItems = this.categories.map((item) => {
      return (<li>...</li>)
    });

    return (
          <div id="announcements-tab">
            List Items:
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
              {listItems}
            </ul>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I expected to see all list items but none(only "listItems" string)in html, no error in console. how can I fix and debug it ? using "debugger" keyword shows nothing for observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, I don't see where are you creating the instance of `AnnouncementState`. Here an example how can you get the categories list.
e.g.

```
class AnnouncementState {

   @observable categories =[];

   @action getAnnouncementCategory() {
        fetch(`..`)
          .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
          })
          .then((response) => {
        this.categories = response.value.map((item , i)=>{ return {Id:item.Id, Title:item.Title} });
          }, (error) => {
          });
      }
}

export default new AnnouncementState(); //here you can create the instance.


@observer
@inject('store') //here substitute with your store name, the name you set in your provider
class AnnouncementComponent extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    debugger
    this.props.store.getAnnouncementCategory();
  }

  render() {
    const listItems = this.props.store.categories.map((item) => {
      return (<li>...</li>)
    });

    return (
          <div id="announcements-tab">
            List Items:
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
              {listItems}
            </ul>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This should work, just be sure you pass the correct store with `<Provider store={store}>`.

Comment: "@inject('store')" I see this inject stuff some places, why do I need it? is it for dependency injection? I didnt use inject but my code still works so when do you need it ?

Comment: Is for example when you have a component inside another component, to avoid to pass all the way down your store, you just use Provider to pass the store, and Inject to take the instance on that specific component.