# render method not triggered with observable array update

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Data loading with fetch method in Repo class fine, but I couldnt pass it component, actually I expect it to re-render of observer component but its not happenning. Here they are;

MenuComponent.tsx:

```
@observer
@inject('params')
class MenuComponent extends React.Component<{params?:IMenuModel[]}, {}> {
  render() {
    //params undefined.
    var menuJSX : JSX.Element[] = this.props.params ? this.props.params.map((item:IMenuModel, i:number)=>{
      return (<li key={item.Id}>{item.itemName}</li>)
    }):[];
    return render(){...}
```

MenuRepo.tsx:

```
class MenuRepo {
  @observable menuItems?: IMenuModel[];
  constructor() {
    this.getItems();
  }
  @action getItems(): void {
    fetch(`..`).then((response: Response): Promise<{ value: IMenuModel[] }> => {
        this.menuItems = [
          { Id: 1, itemName: 'test-item1', childItems: [] }
        ];//property setted here..
    })
      }
  }
export default new MenuRepo;
```

App.tsx;

```
import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import menuCodes from './components/MenuRepo';
class App extends React.Component<null, null> {   
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Menu params = {menuCodes.menuItems}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I checked execution order, jsx render method not re-render after setting observerable field(menuItems) in fetch.

Comment: how are you passing the store? Yo need to use **Provider** to pass the store. See an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268727/react-getting-observable-values-in-component/42275527#42275527

Comment: @Hosar "<Menu params = {menuCodes.menuItems}/>" isnt this pass the store ? I saw tutorial they pass it this way

Comment: do you mean I need to use "import {Provider} from 'mobx-react';"  ? but many samples dont use it ?

Answer (score 0):

try reversing the order here...from this

```
@observer
@inject('params')
```

to this...

```
@inject('params')
@observer
```

[from documentation:](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject) When using both @inject and @observer, make sure to apply them in the correct order: observer should be the inner decorator, inject the outer. There might be additional decorators in between.